# Intellij IDEA: How to enable TypeScript development for node apps?

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript

I've read as much info as I could, be I still get `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.` What else do I have to do to be able to develop for node.js in IDEA with TypeScript?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm using WebStorm but not the built in definition references, I am pulling them in manually. And I reference the node.d.ts via: /// <reference path="../typings/node/node.d.ts"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What else do I have to do to be able to develop for node.js in IDEA with TypeScript

The reference you added is *only valid to give you type information for JavaScript projects*. For TypeScript you need to explicitly have `node.d.ts` in your project and properly `/// <reference`ed.

you can get `node.d.ts` from TSD https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd `tsd install node`